# Where can I see all my +1 and app ratings?

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

Where can I see all my +1 and app ratings?

Answer (score 0):

In [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store), click the `My Play activity` link.

[image]

[Source](http://www.androidcentral.com/see-all-your-ratings-and-pluses-google-play-web).